Is a monotone bijection on $\mathbb N$ necessarily the identity map?
A junior fellow gave me this problem as a doubt.

Let $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be increasing and a bijection then show that $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

I could prove this easily using induction. The base case is like this... Suppose $f(1)\neq 1$ then $f(1)\geq 2$ and since $f$ is monotone, we miss $1$ from the image of $f$ (contradiction). Thus, $f(1)=1$.
But they are not satisfied with the solution. I would love to see some alternative and a generalisation of this result. For instance, if we replace $\mathbb N$ by $\mathbb Q$, the result does not hold since $x\mapsto 2x$ is a counter example. What is the property of $\mathbb N$ that made the difference?

Does your $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$ or not? It usually does in set theory so the base case would be $0$. You can also argue like this: if $f$ is not identity then there is a least $n$ such that $f(n)\neq n$, and then derive a contradiction using monotonicity (this is really induction in disguise). The property of $\mathbb{N}$ that makes this work is that it is well-ordered, namely every nonempty subset has a least element.

@183orbco3 I've read the Peano axioms and they include $0$ in $\mathbb N$. However, in my country we tend to use $\mathbb N$ interchangeably with $\mathbb Z^+$. To include zero, we would use $\mathbb W$ (the set of whole numbers). :(

Don't see what's wrong with induction.  But we can be clearer in our statement.  $P(k):=$ for all $m \le k$ we have $f(m)=m$. In the base case we should point out why $f(1)\ne 1 \implies f(1)\ge 2$ and why $f(1)\ge 2$ should imply that for any $m\ne 1$ we can't have $f(m)=1$. and ... actually you don't have and induction step!... But more to the point well ordering principal (the twin sibling of induction) may be more straightforward... Anyhow, your induction proof should be fine if you clean it up.  But you do need to clean it up.

"What is the property of N that made the difference?"  Natural numbers are well ordered.  Notice it also fails for $\mathbb Z$ (Use $f(x) = x + 1$)

I suppose if we were noodling:  We can start with and $n_0$ and recursively define $n_{k+1}=f(n_k)$.  As $f$ is bijective we can define $n_{-1}=f^{-1}(n_0)$ and $n_{k-1}=f^{-1}(n_k)$.  As $f$ is strictly increasing we have either an infinite chain of $...<n_{-2}<n_{-1}<n_0<n_1<n_2<...$ or of $... > n_{-2}> n_{-1} > n_0>n_1>n_2$ or of $...=n_{-2}=n_{-1}=n_0=n_1=n_2$.  As these are natural numbers we're talking about, if $n_0< n_1$ the inequal infinite chains can only go a finite number in one direct which is a contradiction.  (That's a naive proof but I'd give it full credit.)

Well, your induction proof.... doesn't have an inductive step!
Let $P(n)$ be:  $f(n) = n$
Base case (can be done for $0$ or $1$ depending on you definition of $\mathbb N$.  That is not relevant.  I'll do it for $0\not \in \mathbb N$)
$f(1) =1$.  If $f(1)\ne 1$ then $f(1)=c$ for some natural number $c\ne 1$.  As $1$ is the smallest natural number $c > 1$.  As $f$ is strictly increasing for any $n \ge 1$ we have $f(n) \ge f(1)= c> 1$.  So there is not $n$ where $f(n)=1$.  So the function is not surjective. That contradicts its a bijection so $f(1) = 1$.
Inductive step:
Assume $f(n) = n$. As $f$ is increasing $f(n+1) > f(n) = n$.  In other words, $f(n+1) \ge n+1$.  Suppose $f(n+1) \ne n+1$.  As $f(n+1) \ge n+1$,  $f(n+1) \ne n+1 \implies f(n+1)> n+1$.  Let $f(n+1)=c > n+1$.
We claim there is no $m$ so that $f(m) = n+1$.  If $m \le n$ then as $f$ is increasing $f(m) \le n < n+1$.  If $m > n$ then $m \ge n+1$ and so $f(m) \ge f(n+1)=c > n+1$.  Thus we have a contradiction that $f$ is not surjective.  so $f(m+1) = m+1$.

But are you familiar with the well ordering principal.

Every non-empty subset of $\mathbb N$ has a least element.

Suppose $K = \{n\in \mathbb N| f(n)\ne n\}$.
Outline of proof:  If $K$ is empty then $f$ is identity. (Because if $K$ is empty, there are not $n$ so that $f(n)\ne n$ so for all $n$ we have $f(n)=n$.)
We are going to prove $K$ is empty.
To prove $K$ is empty we are going to prove that $K$ does not have a least element.  (By well-ordering principal, every non-empty subset has a least element. So if $K$ does not, it must be empty.)
To prove $K$ does not have a least element we will show that for any arbitrary $k\in K$ that $k$ is not the least element of $K$.  If no arbitrary $k\in K$ can be the least element, then $K$ doesn't have a least element.
So we are going to assume $k \in K$ and we will prove that $k$ is not the least element of $K$.  That will be a sufficient proof.  Got it? Let's go:
Let $k \in K$ so $f(k) \ne k$.  Let $f(k)=m$.  As $f$ is surjective there must be a $w$ so that $f(w)=k$.  As $f(w)=k\ne f(k)$ we have $w\ne k=f(w)$ so $w\in K$.  And as $f$ is injective and $k\ne m$ we must have $m=f(k)\ne f(m)$.  So $m \in K$.
So recap:  We have $w,k,m \in K$ and $f(w)=k$ and $f(k)=m$.
If $m < k$ then $k$ is not the least element of $K$.
If $k < m$ then $f(w) = k < m = f(k)$.  As $f$ is strictly increasing, $w < k$.  So $k$ is not the least element of $K$.
(And, of course, we've already established $k \ne m$.)
That's it.  We are done.
To recap.  If $k \in K$ then either $f(k)=m < k$ or $w=f^{-1}(k) < k$.  So $k$ can't be the least element of $K$.  As $k$ was completely arbitrary. $K$ can not have a least element. All non-empty subsets of the natural numbers have a least element, so $K$ can't be non-empty.  So $K$ is empty and so for all $n\in \mathbb N; n\not \in K$ so $f(n) = n$ and so $f$ is the identity.

I made some edits. See if you like them.

I'm familiar with the well-ordering principle but I couldn't figure out that it makes the difference. So other than $\mathbb N$, with some modifications, the proof also works for  a set $X\subset \mathbb Z$ containing finitely many non-positive integers.

...um... true.  I hadn't that about that but any set that contains a finite number of non natural real numbers must have a least element as any non-positive is less than any postive and the set of non-positives if finite so it has a least element.

The relevant property of $\mathbb N$ is being well-ordered: any subset of $\mathbb N$ has a smallest element.
We can prove the same thing for any well-ordered set $S$. Let $f \colon S \to S$ be a non-identity monotone bijection, and let $x$ be the smallest element such that $f(x) \ne x$. In fact, we must have $f(x) > x$, because for any $y < x$, $y$ is $f(y)$ and cannot be $f(x)$.
Let $z$ be the element of $S$ such that $f(z) = x$. If $z < x$, this contradicts our choice of $x$, because $z$ is smaller than $x$ and yet $f(z) \ne z$. If $z > x$, this contradicts monotonicity: $x < z$ but $f(x) > x = f(z)$. Either way, we conclude that $f$ cannot exist.

The statement to prove is:
$f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ is bijective and increasing $\Longrightarrow f$ is the identity map, namely $f(n)=n, \space \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Proof.
Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ a bijective and increasing function that is not the identity map.
Then, exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n_0)\ne n_0$.
Using the fact that $f$ is increasing, we can find a contradiction with the surjectiveness.
We have two cases.
If $f(n_0)<n_0$, then $f(n)\leq f(n_0)<n_0,\space\space \forall n<n_0$ because $f$ is increasing.
This implies that $f$ cannot take on the values ​​$\{n_0,n_0+1,n_0+2,...\}$, contradicting the fact that it is surjective.
On the other hand, if $f(n_0)>n_0$, then $f(n)\geq f(n_0)> n_0, \space \space \forall n>n_0$, because $f$ is increasing.
This implies that $f$ cannot take on the values ​​$\{n_0,n_0-1,n_0-2,...\}$, contradicting the fact that it is surjective.
Therefore, such function $f$ cannot exists.
$\Box$
